# Remove standard title from Magento bundled products

Tags: magento, bundle, title

Hope anybody can help me on this matter.

I want to delete the standard title from the bundled products, but I can not find where to do this.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks and regards

### Extra information

In my email confirmation I see:

Test Bundled products (= product name)

[title]
1x Product A - € 5.00     SKU1
[title]
1x Product B - € 5.00     SKU2

I already cleared the price in /app/code/local/Mage/Bundle/Block/Sales/Orders/Items/Renderer.php, but the [title] must be hidden or gone in my email notification so it finally looks like this:

1x Product A - € 5.00     SKU1
1x Product B - € 5.00     SKU2

---

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can change product meta title check below path
Admin->Catalog->manage products->select particular product->meta information -> add meta title -> save

Comment: I need to delete the bundled product title, not the meta title.
Thanks though for your reaction.

Answer (score 0):

In your phtml template you can replace:

`<?php echo $this->getSelectionQtyTitlePrice($_selection) ?>`

with

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_selection->getName()); ?>
<span class="price-notice">
    <span class="price">
        + <?php echo $this->formatPriceString($_selection->getPrice()); ?>        
    </span>
</span>
```